# Magento theme doesnt show login page from theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I am having a problem with my magento shop. It has it's own login special page, and this was working fine before i moved my site towards a magento server. My login page now looks like this:

[Login page my website](http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/nl/customer/account/login/)

but it has to look like this, as the Athlete theme has:

[Theme login page like it has to be](http://athlete.olegnax.com/index.php/customer/account/login/)

i cannot figure out where it is going wrong. Theme is working fine for the rest, only this crashed after moving..

What can it be?

Comment: Too many variables involved here. Do you have the same problem on your development server (hoping you have one setup). For these kinds of issues, I recommend installing https://github.com/astorm/LayoutViewer, then running `url/customer/account/login?showLayout=page` to see if there's any funny business in the generated layout XML. You can also try `showLayout=handles` to ensure that the right `THEME_` handle is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot of things, but try this:

1. First, make sure you have a complete backup (file system and database)
2. Then make sure compilation is disabled in `System > Tools > Compilation`
3. I see you have merged `<JavaScript>` and `<CSS>` files, disable this also in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > JavaScript Settings + CSS Settings`
4. Disable all cache in `System > Cache Management`
5. Use FTP or SSH to delete the following directories (if present)

   ```
   [your Magento install dir]/includes/src/
   [your Magento install dir]/media/css/
   [your Magento install dir]/media/css_secure/
   [your Magento install dir]/media/js/
   [your Magento install dir]/var/cache/
   ```

> **IMPORTANT:** Don't delete the entire `includes/` `media/` and `var/` directories, only the subdirectories I mentioned above!

6. Clear all the cache and cookies of your browser, or try a different browser
7. See if the issue is gone in the frontend

If the issue is not gone then your store may (still) be loading the wrong template file. Enable Magento Profiler in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug` and add Template Path Hints and Block Names to Hints to see if you can discover something more.

Also compare the `<head></head>` section of your store with the one of the Athlete theme to see if all `.js` and `.css` files are loaded correctly. To do this it is important to keep merge `<JavaScript>` and `<CSS>`set to "No".